# a better way to query an array of ID's from graphql using apollo-server

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have a bodybuilding app that tracks the reps of a user for a given exercise, GraphQL is a must since the data is nested like crazy, a user can have multiple plans, which themselves can have multiple Exercises, but the problem is that "Exercises" are Not Specifically related to any User, I want the exercises to be unrelated, and the plans need to refer to the exercises ...
So I stumbled upon this problem of having an array of ID's of an exercises in my Plans, and I want to query them, I'm using Apollo server by the way.

This problem is very similar to the problem of having a profile with a list of friends and I just want to query that list of friends in GraphQL.

Here is my TypeDef:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
type User {
    id:ID,
    username:String,
    password:String,
    isPremium:Boolean,
    age:Int,
    email:String
}
type Plan {
    id:ID,
    exercises:[Exercise],
    user:String
}
type Category {
    id:ID,
    name:String,
    exercises:[Exercise]
}
type Exercise {
    id:ID,
    name:String,
    reps:[Rep]
}
type Rep {
    id:ID,
    exercise:String,
    reps:Int,
    date:String
}
`
```

Comment: back to general (graphql/apollo doesn't matter) DB design step